# É possível com CSS fazer com que cada letra de uma palavra tenha uma cor diferente?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, html-select

```css
.two-colors{
   font-size: 160px;
   background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, green 0);
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
 
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Arial;
  
}



<span class="two-colors">TESTE </span>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<span class="two-colors">TESTE </span>
```

Comment: Se você tiver controle sobre a fonte o próprio gradient dá certo, só faltou acertar as porcentagens (é uma gambiarra lascada, mas é só você fazer por exemplo blue 20%, green 20%, green 40%, red 40%, red 60%, etc (acertando os % pras cores)

Comment: Vc tem que dar mais detalhes, Pq não coloca cada letra dentro de um span e seta um color?

Comment: Queria chegar em um resultado igual dessa imagem https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_665890-MLB31127748573_062019-O.jpg. Quase consegui com o exemplo do amigo @Bacco.

Comment: A sugestão de colocar cada letra dentro de um span e setar uma color é inviável se tratar de um texto por exemplo. Se for umas palavras, funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: @douglasabnovato eu consegui colocando o span e setar color em cada letra. E também consegui com a reposta do nosso amigo Bacco. Mas para um texto fica muito complicado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considero "apelação", mas só pra dizer que esse caminho que começou na pergunta seria um jeito:

```css
.two-colors {
   font-size: 160px;
   background: linear-gradient(to right,
      blue 20%,
      green 20%, green 40%,
      red 40%, red 60%,
      orange 60%, orange 80%,
      purple 80%
    );
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
 
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
Dá certo aqui:<br>
<span class="two-colors">TESTE</span><br>
Aqui já precisaria ajustar tudo, mas ai fica errado pro outro texto:<br>
<span class="two-colors">WIDOW</span><br>
```

Só que fatalmente para fontes com largura variada de caracteres vai ter que ajustar caso a caso manualmente e vai ficar cheio de falhas se o usuário tiver qualquer fonte diferente da que especificou (seja por falha na carga ou qualquer outra restrição).

Resumo: salvo alguma situação muito bizarra, melhor separar no HTML mesmo e usar, por exemplo, um span por letra para não afetar a semântica.